# Account for variability in screen output using python

Tags: python

I am printing out a list of users in AWS. The data prints out to the screen in an uneven way, based on the variability in length of the first column:

```
us-svc-cloudops-aws                           AIDAIDNRJABLEK6Z2MSME         arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/us-svc-cloudops-aws      2019-02-13 19:05:10
us-svc-kadi-aws-jenkins                           AIDAJHPWXCPNWRU6UCRPO         arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/us-svc-kadi-aws-jenkins      2017-05-16 18:35:11
us-svc-ksr                           AIDAIPXXXD3JW3A75QNR2         arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/us-svc-ksr      2018-05-15 20:25:17
us-svc-splunk-aws                           AIDAINU7WJB4O3DHQXCLU         arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/us-svc-splunk-aws      2017-10-03 15:40:59
us-svc-turbomonic-aws                           AIDAIRNXWR5BZOKJZ6TMU         arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/us-svc-turbomonic-aws      2017-10-03 15:53:04
```

Here is my code so far:

```
user_list = client.list_users()
for user in user_list['Users']:
    user_name = user['UserName']
    user_id = user['UserId']
    user_arn = user['Arn']
    create_date = user['CreateDate']
    time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    create_date = str(create_date.strftime(time_format))
    print_string = user_name + '           ' + user_id + '         ' + user_arn + '      ' + create_date
    print(print_string)
```

Here is an example of what a user_list looks like:

```
{'Users': [{'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'bluethundr', 'UserId': 'AIDAVMGUQ5SMEMELAT4YR', 'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/bluethundr', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 16, 39, 1, tzinfo=tzutc())}], 'IsTruncated': False, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '1ccacd69-5749-4284-a690-4a6de43f22f4', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '1ccacd69-5749-4284-a690-4a6de43f22f4, 1ccacd69-5749-4284-a690-4a6de43f22f4', 'date': 'Thu, 25 Apr 2019 15:33:41 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '557'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

I want the output on the screen to be spaced evenly. Is there any way I can achieve this using python?

Comment: Check out [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Or use e.g. `user_name.ljust(...)`

Comment: Thank you! ljust worked perfectly. You should put that as an answer so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Too late, question got closed. It's OK, I already have enough reputation here.  ;-)

Comment: Haha! Ok man. Thanks anyways! You rock!